# Error filter template : Email template '' is not defined

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates

When creating a custom email header for a email template it gives an error in the email's body.

> Error filtering template: Email template '' is not defined

I have placed in the header using this convention in the email template body (which is just overridden in the theme email)

```
{{template config_path="design/email/design_email_header_changed_template"}}
```

I have put the template id into email_templates.xml inside the main module (I know it's bad practice, but for now, please humour me till I fix the main issue)

It is as if it doesn't find it's name for whatever reason or something? It is literally two ' in a row with no name. I did at the time have a - in the label in the section below. It might not have liked that?

```
<template id="design_email_header_changed_template" label="Header Changed" file="changed_header.html" type="html" module="Magento_Email" area="frontend"/>
```

I have put the template header in the module under the frontend folder on the root as well as the theme folder (again, I know bad practice, but I'm just trying to figure out what is going on).

I have also updated the config.xml to include the header template:

```
<header_template>design_email_header_changed_template</header_template>
```

I am unsure of what I am doing wrong for the system to not retrieve the html file to spit out the template or, rather find the template.

Thanks!

Comment: i have same issue

Comment: Please see my answer below -- it may be a good workaround to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't fix the main issue, so this is what I did.

I made the "header" kind of extend to the email body. For example, order_email.html and added a CMS block call to there (I know, right!). Within the main admin area, I created a new CMS block and pasted the image (in my case) there. I made sure to name the block so I would be able to call it in the email.

In certain emails where I wanted the CMS block to show, I did this (Magento_Sales/email/order_new.html) - in a template (var/www/magento2/..../app/design/frontend/theme_name/Magento_Sales/email/order_new.html)- as an example:

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" area='frontend' block_id="thank_you"}}
```

Hope this helps someone! :)

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.3.5, I came across this issue around virtual/physical Gift Card Product. Even though the `Gift Card` admin configurations were correctly set in `Admin > Sales > Gift Cards > Gift Card Email Settings > Gift Card Notification Email Template`, whenever I was invoicing an gift card order it was throwing an error saying - `There was an error creating the invoice`. And in the `var/log/exception.log` file I was seeing the following error:

> report.CRITICAL: Email template '' is not defined.
> {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Email
> template '' is not defined. at
> /vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Config.php:225)"} []

The fix was to:

1. Create a new template for `Gift Card Notification Email Template` in Admin > Marketing > Email Templates
2. Assign this newly created template in the gift card product edit page under `Gift Card Information` tab
3. Also assign the same template in `Admin > Sales > Gift Cards > Gift Card Email Settings > Gift Card Notification Email Template`.
4. Clear cache and the error was fixed and invoice creation was successful.